# Nosetest: add decorator for tests before execution

Tags: python, nose, allure

I  use nosetests and allure framework for reporting purposes. In order to make the report look like I want, I have to add `@nose.allure.feature('some feature')` decorator to each test. The problem is that I have over 1000 test. Is there any way to modify tests before execution?

I was thinking about custom nose plugin, but not sure how can it be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plug-in is definitely the way to go. there is a bunch of documentation on creating plug-ins:

http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc_tests/test_issue119/empty_plugin.html
http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=+plugin

I think you'll probably want to extend the test runner. You can look at what that decorator is doing before and after calling the function, and then just add that stuff in the test runner.

Comment: I have found out what the decorator does - it just adds an attribute to the test, but I can't really determine which method of Plugin interface has to be overridden.

Comment: I've never written one so I can't help you much there.  if I were you I would look at some open source projects for some inspiration. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nose+plug-in+github&*

Comment: That first one might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the decorator to the test classes instead?

Not sure if it will work, but sometimes works nicely for `@patch`.

Comment: that's what I tried to do before, didn't work for me. I guess that allure decorators can only be applied for tests, not classes